# Hard code GA event with GTM

Tags: google-analytics

I want to be able to hard code some GA event such as below. I'm using GTM and I understand its not possible in this way. Is there a way round this?

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Mobile', 'Original', 'App');
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do?  Are you able to edit the code of the website?  If so, it's certainly possible to track an event the way you've described.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem because GTM creates a randomly named tracker instead of the default tracker (t0). You can either use the set fields method on the "name" field to set the tracker name to a known values (i.e. "myTracker") and adapt your calls accordingly:

```
ga('myTracker.send', 'event', 'Mobile', 'Original', 'App');
```

Or you can use the ge function to send your event tracking calls to all trackers in the page:

```
ga(function() {
  var trackers = ga.getAll();
  for (var i=0; i<trackers.length; ++i) {
    var tracker = trackers[i];
    tracker.send('event', 'Mobile', 'Original', 'App');
  }
});
```

which will probably create more headache than it's worth. However it is unlikely that there is a scenario that can't be covered without a need to hardcode events - the proper way would be to push a custom GTM event (and your GA event data) to the dataLayer and trigger an GA event tracking call from there.

So for hardcoding event, just don't.

Answer (score 0):

To implement ga event use this syntax wit your onclick.

replace  `ga('send', 'event', 'Mobile', 'Original', 'App');`

with this and it will work:

```
gtag('event', 'click', {'event_category' : 'Mobile',
        'event_action' : 'Original', 'event_label' : 'App'});
```